# Как составить Post запрос на сокращение ссылки в python?

Tags: python, api, post, url

Есть функция, которая обращается к 1-url.ru через post. В приведённом примере неправильно передаётся params. Не понимаю как исправить...
Инструкция к API: https://1-url.ru/api/dev/doc/

```
import requests
def url1(murl):
    longurl = murl
    key = 'nKblTqGhRWqfUDsyskTQJguMLMWcHn3hly1AZBpQTtL3CorReY8oXage0X60A1L9'
    r = requests.post("https://1-url.ru/api/dev/v1/shot", params={'key': key, 'longur': longurl})
    print(r)
    k = r.text
    return k
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def url1(murl):
    longurl = murl
    key = 'nKblTqGhRWqfUDsyskTQJguMLMWcHn3hly1AZBpQTtL3CorReY8oXage0X60A1L9'
    r = requests.post("https://1-url.ru/api/dev/v1/shot", data={"key": key, "longurl": longurl})
    #print(r.json())
    k = r.json()
    return k['fulllink']
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! если это ответ, то, пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]